# How i can make logo grid in flutter that scroll infinity

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

how i can make logo grid in flutter that can scroll automatically to infinity just like in picture,i making this for web.[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [carousuel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carousel_slider](https://%5BBlockquote%5D%5B1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package, which provides (enableInfiniteScroll) option,
which allows you to scroll your logos list in an infinite loop.

```
CarouselSlider(    
      items: items,    
      options: CarouselOptions(
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal))
```